Order given by two probability measures
Let $X$ be a r.v. and two measures $\mathbb{P}$ and \mathbb{Q} such that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[X]\leq \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[X]\quad (1)
\end{equation}
It implies
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[\max(X,m)]\leq \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[\max(X,m)]
\end{equation}
for any $m\in\mathbb{R}$? My intuition suggests this is true, since the function $f(x)=max(x,m)$
is non-decreasing. I believe instead that (1) implies
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[f(x)]\leq \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[f(x)]
\end{equation}
for any non-decreasing function. "I haven't had any success in proving it. Any help or advise would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

This does not hold. Consider the case where $\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X=10) = 1/2$ and $\mathbb{Q}(X=6) = 1$.
Then we have
$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[X] = 5 < 6 = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[X],$$
but if $m=5$ then
$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\max(X,m)] = 7.5 > 6 = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[\max(X,m)].$$
The property you are looking for is related to the notion of stochastic dominance/domination.

The difference between the $E_P[X]$ and $E_P[\max(X,m)]$ changes the left side/tail of the distribution. This can have different effects for different distributions.
So you can have $$E_P[X]<E_Q[X]$$ but after the tail get's censored $$E_P[\max(m,X)]>E_Q[\max(m,X)]$$
An example is this comparison between two binomial distributions

The Binom(6,0.5) has a lower mean than Binom(4,0.8), but with a larger probability mass on the high values.
